# Redirected to ad websites on hyperlink click

Tags: virus

I have a website developed using Codeigniter & MySql. The website is working fine, however, of late I have noticed that when I hover over the link it shows me the correct page but when I click on it, most of the time it opens a new tab showing some random website. This problem happens on my localhost as well. I have scanned my laptop for viruses/adwares but no infection found.

The url of the website is:
http://reporterpost.in/

Please suggest how do I get rid of this problem. Other websites on my laptop don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Chrome blocked resource <URL> on this site because this site tends to show ads that interrupt, distract, mislead, or prevent user control. Learn more at <URL>
```

```
www-embed-player.js:553 Chrome blocked resource https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id on this site because this site tends to show ads that interrupt, distract, mislead, or prevent user control. Learn more at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5738264052891648
```

In my chrome, these alert is appeared in chrome console.

I guessed `google adsense` is applied to http://reporterpost.in/.

Did you apply adsense to website?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @leesh. Yes, I did apply for adsense on my website but it was not approved for some other reasons. For the sake of testing, I removed the adsense related js codes and run the website on localhost. The problem still persists. :(

Comment: @gomeshmunda Did you see all adsense file? My chrome console just said that some codes of file related with `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id` were banned by **chrome pop-up blocker**.

Comment: @gomeshmunda Or `onesignal` may be cause of your problem. Because I did some analysis of your website, I found `onesignal` 's `Ad modal` which has some strange links like `<link rel="preconnect" href="//sehoweve.fun">` and `<link rel="preconnect" href="//hinksdeba.top">`. How about getting rid of code related **OneSignal** ?

Comment: based on your suggestions and analysis, I carried out some tests by removing some js codes and found that a 'Daily horoscope' js code snippet was causing the problem. Now I have removed all the offending codes and its working fine on my local machine. Thanks for looking into my problem.